# YARN - log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException (Is a directory)

Tags: hadoop, oozie-workflow

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1502783189107_0007/container_1502783189107_0007_01_000001 (Is a directory)
    `
```

Please provide me a suggestion when I am running sqoop with oozie I am facing the error above